# Adding Sparkline in via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a `spark line` in for a range of cells.  The following line throws a mismatch error at me, however, the `spark line` still appears correctly even though the code will not finish executing.

I understand that `.SourceData` takes in a string, but when I checked the variable type of `rangeTest.address`, it returned a type string.  This is where I believe my error is coming from.  Can anyone offer some help.

```
Set spark = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(18, 5).SparklineGroups.Add(Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:=rangeTest.Address)
```

Comment: How is `spark` declared?

Comment: I declared it as a sparkline `Dim spark As Sparkline`

Comment: Hmm, so I changed the declaration to an `object` and that solved it.  I would love to know why the `sparkline` declaration was giving me trouble.

Comment: If you take a look at the docs online the return type is SparkGroup

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837827.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @TimWilliams